Servidor web con powershell
Estoy aquí para preguntar si es posible crear un servidor web usando solo powershell sin nodejs ni python ni nada mas. Le dije a chatgpt que me diera un ejemplo y este fue el código:
$listener = New-Object System.Net.HttpListener

# Define los URI que el listener escuchará
$listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:8080/")

# Inicia el listener
try {
    $listener.Start()
    Write-Output "Servidor web iniciado en http://localhost:8080/"
} catch {
    Write-Error "No se pudo iniciar el servidor web: $_"
    exit
}

# Maneja las solicitudes entrantes
while ($true) {
    try {
        # Espera una solicitud
        $context = $listener.GetContext()
        
        # Obtiene el objeto de respuesta
        $response = $context.Response
        
        # Define el contenido de la respuesta
        $responseString = "<html><body><h1>Hola desde PowerShell!</h1></body></html>"
        $buffer = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($responseString)
        
        # Configura la respuesta
        $response.ContentLength64 = $buffer.Length
        $response.OutputStream.Write($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length)
        
        # Cierra la respuesta
        $response.OutputStream.Close()
    } catch {
        Write-Error "Error al manejar la solicitud: $_"
    }
}

# (Este código no se alcanza, pero es una buena práctica tener un bloque finally)
finally {
    $listener.Stop()
    $listener.Close()
}

El codigo funciona realmente, pero el problema es que necesito que este servidor sirva archivos locales (como live-server) pero solo usando powershell. Los archivos pueden ser html js css txt json obj png jpg gif, etc. Si es posible espero respuestas, gracias

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Mas que respuestas, estas esperando que alguien lo haga por ti (la primer parte la hizo una IA) y el sitio no funciona asi.. aqui damos soluciones a problemas concretos.. no hacemos el trabajo por otros.. por ejemplo, que averiguaste sobre el siguiente paso???

Lee los enlaces que te pase... ;)
